# Saving variables in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, session, variables

I'm trying to convert a game I made (WindowsFormApplication) to an ASP.NET page.

My Problem is that I have a lot "private" variables in my WindowFormApplication and those variables are important for the game. But when after I Declare all my variables (in my Page_Load), they turn null no matter what I do(click a button, refresh the page).

Is there anyway to save my variables between buttons (other than Session, because I'd have to create like 6 more sessions)

Comment: Can you post your code (a representative example)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to save your variables in the `ViewState` object:

```
ViewState["MyValue"] = 3;
...
int myValue = (int)ViewState["MyValue"];
```

If you already have a property then you can just use the `ViewState` to hold the value, such as:

```
private int MyValue
{
    set { ViewState["MyValue"] = value; }
    get { return (int)ViewState["MyValue"]; }
}
```

If your value needs to be available in the whole application (but specific to the current user), you can use `Session` instead of `ViewState`.

If you are worried about people messing with the ViewState then here are two options:

1. [ViewState encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479501.aspx)
2. [Storing the ViewState in the server memory](http://www.aspnetajaxtutorials.com/2009/04/how-to-store-viewstate-in-cache-memory.html)

Comment: It is worth noting that if the variables are saved in the ViewState the user can change the values and eventually cheat.

Comment: By the way, you can still store it in the Session as well. If you have 6 variables it just means storing 6 variables in 1 session, not creating 6 different sessions.

Comment: Yea thats what I meant 6 variables in 1 session ofcourse. The private int MyValue{get ...;set...;) was perfect, exacly what I needed! (I used Session Eventually)